# Why do I have to use the subjuntive mood when translating "I'm so glad that it's you" into Spanish?

Tags: gramática

In my textbook it says the following:

> seas = Second person familiar form - Indicates something might be.

It then gives the following examples to show how it works:

Example 1:

> [I hope] that you be [a nice person].
>   que seas

Example 2:

> [I'm so glad] that it's [you]!
>   que seas

I understand the first example, because the speaker is hoping the the other person might be nice.
But I don’t get the second example. 
How can `“it’s”` be something that `might be`?

Why does Spanish language use `Seas` to mean `It's`?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but it seems the _que_ is introducing a [low] degree of incertainty, since you could also say _me alegra que no sea él_. The only firm fact here is the 1st person is happy. Consistently if you use _saber_, you use the indicative mood, because you are explicitly cancelling said uncertainty: _Yo sé que eres tú_. If you want to say the opposite (you are not certain) you still use subjunctive: _No estoy seguro de que seas tú_/_No me consta que seas tú_.

Comment: You don't just use subjunctive when there's doubt.  You also use when you are being subjective and/or inserting emotion.

Comment: @gufia so in example 2, the speaker is using `seas` to show that he is really happy that it's you?

Comment: @big_smile he's not using it to show anything per se, because using *eres* isn't an option.  Because the *que eres* clause gets colored with the emotion of *estoy feliz* or *me alegra*, it ends up in subjunctive as *que seas*, and in fact *me alegra que eres* is grammatically incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, it seems my comment was at least incomplete. The rules of when to use the subjunctive may be complex.

[This article](http://www.elsubjuntivo.com/usos.html) enumerates twelve cases in which the subjunctive should be used. Among these:

> Para expresar emoción o sentimiento. *(To express emotions or feelings.)*

FWIW, subjunctive is always difficult to non-native speakers (and even to native ones). Practice will be your best teacher to acquire a strong sense on when to use it.

Trying to find a pattern with other rules, it seems that there underlies a sense of vagueness/lack of concreteness: the subject is expressing that the fact (that *it's you*/the listener) will *always* make them happy rather than just this specific (concrete) time.